# How should we interpret the results of the H2O predict function?

Tags: python-3.x, h2o

I have trained and stored a random forest binary classification model. Now I'm trying to simulate processing new (out-of-sample) data with this model. My Python (Anaconda 3.6) code is:

```
import h2o
import pandas as pd
import sys

localH2O = h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, max_mem_size = "8G", nthreads = -1)
h2o.remove_all()

model_path = "C:/sm/BottleRockets/rf_model/DRF_model_python_1501621766843_28117";
model = h2o.load_model(model_path)

new_data = h2o.import_file(path="C:/sm/BottleRockets/new_data.csv")
print(new_data.head(10))

predict = model.predict(new_data)  # predict returns a data frame
print(predict.describe())
predicted = predict[0,0]
probability = predict[0,2]  # probability the prediction is a "1"

print('prediction: ', predicted, ', probability: ', probability)
```

When I run this code I get:

```
>>> import h2o
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import sys
>>> localH2O = h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, max_mem_size = "8G", nthreads = -1)
Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54321. connected.
--------------------------  ------------------------------
H2O cluster uptime:         22 hours 22 mins
H2O cluster version:        3.10.5.4
H2O cluster version age:    18 days
H2O cluster name:           H2O_from_python_Charles_0fqq0c
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster free memory:    6.790 Gb
H2O cluster total cores:    8
H2O cluster allowed cores:  8
H2O cluster status:         locked, healthy
H2O connection url:         http://localhost:54321
H2O connection proxy:
H2O internal security:      False
Python version:             3.6.1 final
--------------------------  ------------------------------
>>> h2o.remove_all()
>>> model_path = "C:/sm/BottleRockets/rf_model/DRF_model_python_1501621766843_28117";
>>> model = h2o.load_model(model_path)
>>> new_data = h2o.import_file(path="C:/sm/BottleRockets/new_data.csv")

Parse progress: |█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100%
>>> print(new_data.head(10))
  BoxRatio    Thrust    Velocity    OnBalRun    vwapGain
----------  --------  ----------  ----------  ----------
     1.502    55.044        0.38          37       0.845

[1 row x 5 columns]

>>> predict = model.predict(new_data)  # predict returns a data frame

drf prediction progress: |████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100%
>>> print(predict.describe())
Rows:1
Cols:3


         predict    p0                  p1
-------  ---------  ------------------  -------------------
type     enum       real                real
mins                0.8849431818181818  0.11505681818181818
mean                0.8849431818181818  0.11505681818181818
maxs                0.8849431818181818  0.11505681818181818
sigma               0.0                 0.0
zeros               0                   0
missing  0          0                   0
0        1          0.8849431818181818  0.11505681818181818
None
>>> predicted = predict[0,0]
>>> probability = predict[0,2]  # probability the prediction is a "1"
>>> print('prediction: ', predicted, ', probability: ', probability)
prediction:  1 , probability:  0.11505681818181818
>>>
```

I am confused by the contents of the "predict" data frame.  Please tell me what the numbers in the columns labeled "p0" and "p1" mean.  I hope they are probabilities, and as you can see by my code, I am trying to get the predicted classification (0 or 1) and a probability that this classification is correct.  Does my code correctly do that?

Any comments will be greatly appreciated.
Charles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

p0 is the probability (between 0 and 1) that class 0 is chosen.

p1 is the probability (between 0 and 1) that class 1 is chosen.

The thing to keep in mind is that the "prediction" is made by applying a threshold to p1.  That threshold point is chosen depending on whether you want to reduce false positives or false negatives.  It's not just 0.5.

The threshold chosen for "the prediction" is max-F1.  But you can extract out p1 yourself and threshold it any way you like.

Comment: So, in my example, the predicted value was 1 (from the table) with a probability of 0.1150.  Why was the predicted value computed to be 1 with such a low probability?

Comment: By the way, if I run "model.display()", I get a lot of printout.  There is a table called "metrics" that contains: "max f1  10.0741772  0.571429".  So... how can I apply this information?  I need a formula that I can use to evaluate streaming data to see if I have a valid classification.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From that, I guess that "1" is class 0. So the p0 was 0.885, which is greater than the 0.571 of Max F1, which is why `predict` is "1".   (If that is still not making sense you might want to post the first few rows of your training data.)

Comment: Darren, it's the value of p1 which is compared, not p0.  And the '1' is class 1.  See here for the code that's used to calculate this for the POJO/MOJO.  The function is getPrediction().  https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/GenModel.java#L269

Comment: Forgive me for belaboring the point.  I still have my training wheels on. I'm still not getting an answer to my question: If the probability of getting class 1 (p1) is less than 0.5, how can h2o predict 1, regardless of the threshold number? Applying the threshold to the prediction seems to imply that there is a weak or strong prediction.  Is this how we should think about it?

Comment: 0.5 isn't a threshold.  In fact, 0.5 isn't anything.  I only brought it up because new people think "it's under 0.5, how can the answer be 1?".  (That used to be me.  :)  So people have been taught by math classes that 0.5 is the rounding point, but the model doesn't know anything about 0.5.  For the model, max-F1 (not 0.5) is the threshold.  And yes, you could think of the distance of p1 from max-F1 as the strength of the prediction.

Answer (score 1):

Darren Cook asked me to post the first few lines of my training data. Here is is:

```
   BoxRatio  Thrust  Velocity  OnBalRun  vwapGain  Altitude
0     0.000   0.000     2.186     4.534     0.361         1
1     0.000   0.000     0.561     2.642     0.909         1
2     2.824   2.824     2.199     4.748     1.422         1
3     0.442   0.452     1.702     3.695     1.186         0
4     0.084   0.088     0.612     1.699     0.700         1
```

The response column is labeled "Altitude".  Class 1 is what I want to see from new "out-of-sample" data.  "1" is good, and it means that "Altitude" was reached (true positive).  "0" means that "Altitude" was not reached (true negative). In the predict table above, "1" was predicted with a probability of 0.11505681818181818.  This does not make sense to me.

Charles