# h2o binary classification, understand p0 and p1

Tags: h2o

I have already read this question: [How should we interpret the results of the H2O predict function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523997/how-should-we-interpret-the-results-of-the-h2o-predict-function)
Still don't understand if p1 is the probability between [0,1] and could be used equally as it 's a regression and i can apply my own threshold

edit: 
thank you for your answer still have some confusion about it, let's dig it suppose my outcome Y is [0,1], if  Y is numeric i run it as REGRESSION and i have a single column as response. On the other hand if Y is factor run it as CLASSIFICATION and the output is: prediction/p0/p1. NOW, is p1 the same as use Y as numeric? 
Also http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/calibrate_model.html  calibrate_model parameter affects logloss but now the max F1 is still used as threshold on P0 P1 or on the calibrated probabilities? Can i use the calibrated probabilities for regression as the logloss is supposed less?

Comment: Data type of `Y` doesn't define if the problem is regression or classification. The semantic does so if `Y` contains {0,1} values only (never mind numeric or character) it probably begs classification. Hence predict probability and use classification. Just cast numeric to `enum` type using something like `train.df['Y'] = as.factor(train.df['Y'])`.

Comment: in h2o if Y [0,1] is a factor it perform a classification, if is.numeric a regression

Comment: from h2o docs: The data type of the response column determines the model category. If the response is a categorical variable (also called a factor or an enum), then a classification model is created. If the response column data type is numeric (either integer or real), then a regression model is created.

Comment: code above shows how to change `Y`'s type from numeric to factor. Again, it's about semantic and not about its formal type.

Comment: The trick is understanding that regardless of whether you are doing a classification or regression problem H2O will build a regression tree, because the tree isn’t predicting a class it is predicting a value between 0 and 1 (which is the uncalibrsted probability). So for a binary target you are not doing a regression problem.

Answer (score 3):

the output of a binary classification problem for H2O will give you the class label (where the threshold is set to get you the max F1 score), the predicted value of class 0 (p0), and the predicted value of class 1 (p1).

These predicted values are uncalibrated probabilities, if you want actual probabilities you need to set H2O's model argument `calibrate_model` to True.

**So to answer your question**, yes `p1` is the predicted value between 0 and 1 (for example you will see values like .23, .45. , .89, etc.) and because H2O builds regression trees you could technically use `1-p0` to get your `p1` value (or vice versa)  and in fact unless you set `binomial_double_trees = True` this is exactly what H2O is doing: it builds a single regression tree for one of the classes and then takes 1-(that class value) to get the predicted values for the other class.